# Chef doesn't create home directory for user

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, chef-solo, test-kitchen

I have a chef recipe to  create a deploy user. The user is being created when running `kitchen converge`. When trying to create the `.ssh` folder for the user it fails with because the home directory for the user does not exists. `Parent directory /home/deploy does not exist, cannot create /home/deploy/.ssh`.

#### cookbooks/main/recipes/user.rb

```
user deploy do
  action :create
  comment 'Application deploy user'
  home "/home/#{node['deploy_user']}"
  shell '/bin/bash'
  system true
  supports manage_home: true
end

directory "/home/#{node['deploy_user']}/.ssh" do
  mode 0700
  owner node['deploy_user']
  group node['deploy_user']
end

template "/home/#{node['deploy_user']}/.ssh/authorized_keys" do
  mode 0600
  owner node['deploy_user']
  source 'authorized_keys.erb'
end
```

#### .kitchen.yml

```
---
driver:
  name: vagrant

provisioner:
  name: chef_solo

platforms:
  - name: ubuntu-14.04
  - name: centos-7.1

suites:
  - name: default
    run_list:
      - recipe[main::default]
    attributes:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You passed `deploy` to the user resource name instead of `node['deploy_user']`:

```ruby
user node['deploy_user'] do
  action :create
  comment 'Application deploy user'
  home "/home/#{node['deploy_user']}"
  shell '/bin/bash'
  system true
  supports manage_home: true
end
```

Comment: The code seems right to me. Perhaps the error is somewhere else, could it be?

Answer (score 3):

This infuriated me to no end as well. No excuse for Chef not to make such a simple routine action easy to perform.

As this is a top google search and I'm not clear the other answers are proper, here is exactly what I needed to run to get this to work. I'm using chef server 12.4 and client 12.10.24. All on Ubuntu 14.04.

```
user '<USERNAME>' do
  gid '<MY_GROUP_NAME>'
  shell '/bin/bash'
  comment 'some stuff i want to say'
  home "/home/<USERNAME>"
  supports manage_home: true
  action :create
end
```

My /etc/login.defs file is unmodified default.

Answer (score 0):

From `man useradd`:

```
-r, --system
    Create a system account.

    System users will be created with no aging information in /etc/shadow, and their numeric identifiers are choosen in the SYS_UID_MIN-SYS_UID_MAX range, defined in /etc/login.defs, instead of UID_MIN-UID_MAX (and their GID counterparts for the creation of groups).

    Note that useradd will not create a home directory for such an user, regardless of the default setting in /etc/login.defs (CREATE_HOME). You have to specify the -m options if you want a home directory for a system account to be created.
```

Or in short, add `manage_home true` to your resource.

Comment: I've tried with `manage_home true` and `supports manage_home: true` neither works.

Comment: Run with `-l debug` and check what command ends up getting run. Generally speaking if you want a home dir and other user-like behavior, you shouldn't use `system true`.

Comment: debug is pretty long. I'm not sure what to look for.

Comment: You are looking for the command being run to create the user.

Comment: All I see is `Recipe: main::user
         * user[deploy] action create[2016-01-05T22:10:52+00:00] INFO: Processing user[deploy] action create (main::user line 1)
       [2016-01-05T22:10:52+00:00] DEBUG: Providers for generic user resource enabled on node include: [Chef::Provider::User::Useradd]
       [2016-01-05T22:10:52+00:00] DEBUG: Provider for action create on resource user[deploy] is Chef::Provider::User::Useradd`

Comment: What is after the "Provider for action..." line? Maybe add it to the question where it will be nicer formatted

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it's the run sequence problem. Try

```
user node['deploy_user'] do
  comment 'Application deploy user'
  home "/home/#{node['deploy_user']}"
  shell '/bin/bash'
  system true
  manage_home true
end.run_action(:create)
```